# Python for loop output outside of for loop and format

Tags: python, loops

I'm a Python newbie and I have a few questions. In the below example I want to use the output of x in the for loop outside of the for loop with while maintaining its format.  I tried to append it to a list outside the loop but when I print the appended variable it does not show in the same format.

Question 1: How can I use the output of the loop outside the loop in the same format?

Question 2: How can I assign the output of the for loop to a variable outside the loop while maintaining the format?

Question 3: Is there any quick way to count the number of unique Colors in the final output? For example Red:2, Blue: 2, Green:1, Orange: 1, White: 2, Black: 1, Purple: 2, Indigo: 1

```
file = '''2016-07-12 08:00   Red     Blue    Green
          2016-07-12 08:00   Red     Orange  White
          2016-07-12 09:00   Blue    Black   Purple
          2016-07-12 10:00   Indigo  Purple  White'''

split_file = file.split('\n')

my_list = []
for i in split_file:
    x = (str(i).split())
    my_list.append(x)
print(my_list)
```

The output in the for looks like this:

```
['2016-07-12', '08:00', 'Red', 'Blue', 'Green']
['2016-07-12', '08:00', 'Red', 'Orange', 'White']
['2016-07-12', '09:00', 'Blue', 'Black', 'Purple']
['2016-07-12', '10:00', 'Indigo', 'Purple', 'White']
```

Output after appending looks like this:

```
[['2016-07-12', '08:00', 'Red', 'Blue', 'Green'], ['2016-07-12', '08:00', 'Red', 'Orange', 'White'], ['2016-07-12', '09:00', 'Blue', 'Black', 'Purple'], ['2016-07-12', '10:00', 'Indigo', 'Purple', 'White']]
```

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I did not get exactly what I was looking for but that is likely because I did not explain my question well.  I want to take the output of the for loop and assign it to a value outside of the for loop like a variable in another function. When I do it only returns one value because I am returning it. When I do list comprehension I lose the formatting and it shows up as a list. How can I assign it to a variable outside the for loop while maintaining the same format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're actually creating two lists when you call `.split()`. If you want to store them in the list, you need a second loop.

```
my_list = []
for i in split_file:
    x = (str(i).split())
    for split in x:
        my_list.append(split)
print(my_list)
```

With respect to your third question, I would suggest using `collections.counter` as suggested in the comments to the answer:

```
for word in ['red', 'blue', 'red', 'green', 'blue', 'blue']:
     cnt[word] += 1
print cnt
```

From the [Python Collections documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html).

Comment: There's actually `collections.Counter` that is for this exact thing.

Comment: updated the answer to reflect the better data structure choice for this problem. didn't know about that, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The first output you have is the x's printed line by line. The second output has all of the x's in an array, so that's why they show comma-separated. If you want to print them in the same format, you'll have to run a for loop on my_list, and call print on each line instead of printing the entire array.

So,

```
for element in my_list:
    print(element)
```